# Change font-size and column width of a table after printing asp.net, javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a table in the code to print, which looks like this:

[image: Web page view]

When I tried to print the table, it's print format looks like this:

[image: Print view]

I need to change the font size of the text in the print view, and also alter the column size in the print view. Also, if I can remove the border in the print view of the web table.

I have used javascript for printing the table. I have made use of the table ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PrintPage() 
{ 

    var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('thisIDisforprinting2'); 
    newWin = window.open(""); 
    newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML); 
    newWin.print(); 
    newWin.close();

} 
</script>
```

Comment: You should post some example code, and what you're trying to accomplish. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: This is the code for printing the table. I have used the table ID.
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintPage() {
        //window.print();
        var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('thisIDisforprinting2');
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

</script>

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a css tag using document.write and style the table as you want using the "print" media query.

function PrintPage() {

```
    var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('thisIDisforprinting2');
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.document.write('<style type="text/css"> @media print { #thisIDisforprinting2 { font-size: 24px; } }</style>');
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

Below a version that set the heigh of the columns and remove the borders

```
    newWin.document.write('<style type="text/css"> @media print { #thisIDisforprinting2 { font-size: 24px; border: none; } #thisIDisforprinting2 td { height: 150px; border: none; } } </style>');
```

Comment: Thank you Jiraiya! I'll try it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Web page may use a width that exceeds the width limits for a printed page. You could try printing the page using the horizontal layout.

Comment: That would not help, as I need to increase the font-size in the print view, and also, remove the border in the print view.